# How to add a 3rd Party dll Reference in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code on mac, i just trying a sample application where i am adding some dll to a new asp.net project using visual studio code, but i am getting this error

/projects/lalkitab.guide/Controllers/HomeController.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name '**dal**' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**where dal is the dll name**

can somebody tell me how to resolve it